# How to prevent Linux from deleting temporary files on shutdown

Tags: linux, files

I am using Ubutu 10.04. I have some apps that create a few temporary files in `/tmp/<file>` as part of their shutdown process. I want to inspect those files when the apps are closed in the event of a system shutdown. However, when the system comes up again I find that all temporary files have been deleted. How can I ask the system not to clear the files in `/tmp/` on shutdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define when files from `/tmp` can be deleted. You should change the value of `TMPTIME` variable form `/etc/default/rcS` file.

The default value of these variable is `0` - these means that files will be deleted every time computer starts. Set up `TMPTIME` to `3` means that will delete files older than 3 days.

But you can set `TMPTIME=infinite` - these means that the files will be never deleted.

Comment: Since my requirement is to inspect the files for debugging purposes, this solution works best for me.

Comment: Not working in 16.04 - tried a number as well as `infinite`, but the files keep on getting deleted. Is there any configuration command to be run after this for the change to take effect?

Answer (score 6):

`/tmp` is often an in memory file system so once you reboot, it's gone.

Instead of trying to preserve `/tmp`, I would try to get my processes to write to a different directory.  If they are written well, the apps should honor the TMPDIR environment variable to decide where to write temp files; you can then have it point to another directory such as `/var/tmp` which should survive a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

you could change the times that  files in /tmp have to be modified in order to delete them.
but if you configure your linux distro to keep the files /tmp for ever and/or a long time then you hard disk will be filled with useless (or not) files in /tmp directory ..
take a look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-removes-files-at-boot-time/)

Comment: Taking into account the comment about /tmp being mounted as a "ramdisk" (aka tmpfs), use the `mount` command to make sure your system wasn't configured that way.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to change where those apps store the temporary files?

A better approach would be to store those files in `/var/tmp`, which is [specifically designed for this](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s15.html).